# ptrace and threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, system-calls, ptrace

I'm working on an linux application incorporating ptrace to observe the threads of another process. When the application I observe forks a child process this already works quite well. By calling waitpid in my application I can obtain the following signals in the observing application:

- `SIGSTOP` form the child process
- `SIGTRAP` from the parent

To keep track of all the children I setup ptrace with `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`, `PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK`, `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE` and `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT`.

While everything is working quite fine with child processes, I cannot observe the threads of the application. I get the `SIGTRAP` from the process creating the thread but I don't get any signals from the thread.

Is there anything special with threads and `ptrace`? How does `strace` keep track of threads (I could not find any special routines dedicated to threads in the code of `strace`)?

This is how I use `ptrace` in my application:

- First I attach to a process: `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);`
- Then, I call `waitpid()`: `trace_pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);`
- Set `ptrace` options: `ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE | PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT);`

After attaching to pid I'm calling `waitpid()` in a loop and call `ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS...` for every new task reported by `ptrace`. Of course, I continue the tasks with `SIGCONT` after event handling.

Comment: I think I've come a bit closer to the core of the problem: When a new thread is created I don't even receive the sigstop in the observing process. However,in the ptrace documentatio it sais: "automatically  start  tracing  the  newly cloned process, which will start with a SIGSTOP." How can this happen?

Comment: I've done a bit of further investigation using procfs and a little application using posix threads. All the application does is to start a new thread and sleep for a while. The new thread is also sleeping for a few seconds. As I said, I don'd receive a sigstop with waitpid for the new thread. However the status file in procfs for the new thread is telling me:

Name:   thread_test
State:  t (tracing stop)
Tgid:   2538
Pid:    2545
PPid:   2395
TracerPid: 2540

So the new thread is stopped but waitpid does not receive the stop signal. What's the correct way of tracing threads?

Comment: note that `ptrace(1)`'s man page line 604 states:
"Flags  are  inherited by new tracees created and "auto-attached" via active PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK,
       PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK, or PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE options."
So that means you don't need to call `PTRACE_SETOPTIONS` for every new task.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution myself: I got the signals from all the threads by calling

```
waitpid(-1, &status, __WALL)
```

instead of

```
waitpid(-1, &status, 0)
```